# Long template parameter lists with generic class method definitions

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a template class, for which I define a member function later in the file, is there a way to avoid repeating the long parameter list? For example

```
template<class tempParam1, class tempParam2, class tempParam3>
class Foo {
  ...
  int Bar(int funcParam1, int funcParam2, int funcParam3);
}
template<class tempParam1, class tempParam2, class tempParam3>
int Foo<tempParam1, tempParam2, tempParam3>::Bar(int funcParam1, int funcParam2, int funcParam3) {
  ...
}
```

Is there some way to keep that function definition line from being so long? Having a bunch of methods to define like that is making my code hard to read.

I tried a typedef like

```
template<class tempParam1, class tempParam2, class tempParam3>
typedef Foo<tempParam1, tempParam2, tempParam3> FooClass;
int FooClass::Bar(int funcParam1, int funcParam2, int funcParam3) {
  ...
}
```

But the compiler (g++) complained ("error: template declaration of ‘typedef’").

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you could always use a `#define`. But it might help if you just used shorter parameter names.

Comment: Use shorter names for the template parameters? Popular choices are `T`, `U`, ...

Comment: Those were actually just silly examples, but point taken. I didn't know if there was some clever trick. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Single letter names, really? How are those more appropriate for template parameters than other variables? (Using `T` for the *only* template parameter is OK, just as a function with one variable might as well call it `x`, but the more you have, the longer the names get.)

Comment: a 'class namespace' sort-of thing would be handy for this: `template <class tempParam1, class tempParam2, class tempParam3> class namespace Foo { int Bar(...) { // definition }; // ... more member definitions }` but someone would have to write the proposal for this ;)  (also, the coming module system might provide a better solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the member inside the `class {}` scope, you don't need to repeat the class template parameters.

Perhaps you can eliminate some parameters using the traits idiom, or otherwise compute several parameters from one.

Instead of

```
template< typename size_type, typename volume_type, typename width_type >
```

you could have

```
template< typename param_type >
  ...
    typedef typename measurement_traits< param_type >::size_type size_type;
```

etc.

C++11 does introduce using declarations which are effectively "templated typedefs", but they cannot be used in the nested-name-specifier of a function definition, which is what you are trying to simplify.